# Docker - Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, macos

When I run image "mysql" after my container I see this error "Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated". `it means I have something that uses port 3306.

After running this command,

```
docker container ls
```

I clearly see image "mysql/mysql-server:8.0" that uses 3306 port.

If I just delete it with this command,

```
docker rm -f <container-name>
```

I can run my"mysql" and everything works fine! But when I stop container and run again I see the same problem, because "mysql/mysql-server:8.0" uses 3306 again. How can I fix this, without removing this image every time running a container?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a container stops, Docker keeps it around in case you want to look at the logs or the contents of the container file system. If you don't need that and you want Docker to remove the container completely when it stops, you can add the `--rm` option to the `docker run` command, like this

```
docker run --rm -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

Then, when the container stop, Docker will remove it and free up port 3306, so you can use it again.